# How do I get rid of a blank page while loading?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have used a wordpress template to build a site, one of the core functionalities is to allow users to post projects for work to be done. I have added a "preloader" to all pages in the form of a spinning wheel to let the user know that the page is working that is hidden once the page has loaded.

It works in most cases, however when I am posting a new project for the first time and click the "pay now" button on the final page it takes a really long time to load (10-15s) and it will not display anything while it is loading as outlined in the images below. I thought initially that the script below would help display it again in case the browser was stuck on the old page but that has had no effect.

This behaviour only occurs if I am posting a new project. If I go back a page once the project has been posted the loading wheel is displayed and the load time is very fast. Can anyone help me understand why the preloader I have doesn't work the first time around?

Here is my code for the preloader:

```
    <script>
    const payNowBtn = document.querySelector('.post_bid_btn');
    payNowBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var loadingWheel = document.getElementById('wheel')
        loadingWheel.style.display = 'block'
    });
</script>

 <div class="preloader" id="wheel">
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="ytp-spinner">
                <div class="ytp-spinner-container">
                    <div class="ytp-spinner-rotator">
                        <div class="ytp-spinner-left">
                            <div class="ytp-spinner-circle"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ytp-spinner-right">
                            <div class="ytp-spinner-circle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the code for the page that is taking a long time to load:

```
function ProjectTheme_my_account_pay_with_credits_area_function()
{
        global $current_user, $wpdb, $wp_query;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $uid = $current_user->ID;
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        $post_ar = get_post($pid);



                    do_action('pt_for_demo_work_3_0');


                    
?>



     <div class="account-main-area col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
            <div class="my_box3 border_bottom_0">


                <div class="box_title"><?php _e("Pay with virtual currency",'ProjectTheme'); ?></div>
                <div class="box_content">



           <div class="post no_border_btm" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <div class="image_holder">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pid); ?>"><img width="45" height="45" class="image_class"
                src="<?php echo ProjectTheme_get_first_post_image($pid,45,45); ?>" /></a>
                </div>
                <div  class="title_holder" >
                     <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pid) ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php echo $post_ar->post_title; ?>">
                        <?php


                        echo $post_ar->post_title;


                        ?></a></h2>
                </div>
                <?php

                    if(isset($_GET['pay'])):
                        echo '<div class="details_holder sk_sk_class">';

                            $post_ar    = get_post($pid);
                            $cr     = projectTheme_get_credits($uid);
                            $bid    = projectTheme_get_winner_bid($pid);
                            $amount = $bid->bid;

                            if($cr < $amount) { echo '<div class="error2">'; echo __('You do not have enough credits to pay for this project.','ProjectTheme');
                            echo '</div><div class="clear10 flt_lft"></div>';
                            ?>

                            <div class="tripp">
                            <a class="post_bid_btn" href="<?php echo ProjectTheme_get_payments_page_url('deposit'); ?>"><?php
                            echo __('Add More Credits','ProjectTheme'); ?></a>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                projectTheme_send_email_to_project_payer($pid, $uid, $bid->uid, $amount, '1');
                                echo __('Your payment has been sent.','ProjectTheme');
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                ?>


                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="details_holder sk_sk_class">

                <b>
                 <?php echo __('The price for the project is','ProjectTheme'); ?>: <?php $bid = projectTheme_get_winner_bid($pid); echo projectTheme_get_show_price($bid->bid); ?></b>
                <br/><br/>

               <?php _e("Your credits amount",'ProjectTheme'); ?>: <?php echo projectTheme_get_credits($uid); ?> <?php echo projectTheme_currency(); ?> <br/><br/>
               <a class="post_bid_btn" href="<?php echo ProjectTheme_get_pay_with_credits_page_url($pid, '&pay=yes'); ?>"><?php echo __('Pay Now','ProjectTheme'); ?></a>

               <a class="post_bid_btn" href="<?php echo ProjectTheme_get_payments_page_url('deposit'); ?>"><?php echo __('Add More Credits','ProjectTheme'); ?></a>
                </div><?php endif; ?>


           </div></div>
           </div>


        </div>
<?php
```

[image]
[image]
[image]